# Xcode taking photo/video only in landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios

How do I ensure that when user activates his camera, if the device (iPhone/iPod/iPad) is being hold as portrait, I want to inform user to rotate the device to landscape and take photo/record video in landscape?

However, app (all my UIViewControllers, UITableViewControllers, etc) are in portrait mode only, no landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Check the interface orientation:

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{
  // call methods to take picture
  ....
}
else
{
  // alert the user this device is not landscape mode
  ...
}
```

Comment: well your suggestion is good. however, if the user rotates the device back to portrait mode after the camera is activated (meaning the UIImagePickerController is set to SourceTypeCamera and presentModalViewContoller), then, it beats the purpose. How can I ensure that even if the camera is activated, the "camera" button to snap the photo is disabled until the device is back to landscape orientation.

Comment: I guess you should subclass or category the UIImagePickerController, and override the method -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 autorotation has slightly changed, however, the same approach is still working.

Sample code:

```
@implementation UIImagePickerController (noRotation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation /* iOS 5 */
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations /* iOS 6 */
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

@end
```